# Including Joomla Modules in Tumult Hype Projects

Tags: html, joomla, module

I'm currently building animations with [`Hype`](http://tumult.com/hype/).

What I would like to do is including certain `Joomla` Modules *INTO* my animation. 
For example: I would like to create a sidebar animation in `Hype` which itself includes a `joomla login module`. I know it's possible to include `HTML Widgets` in a `hype` project but I don't know if it's possible to convert a `Joomla Module` into an `HTML Widget`.

I know that's a very specific question but maybe someone here did already try something similar.

Comment: You can't convert a Joomla module to a HTML widget as modules are PHP and HTML based. Have you tried anything of your own so far?

Comment: I tried creating a Hype project and included the "Modules Anywhere" Code. But when I export and upload the Hype project and include it in my homepage, then my "Modules Anywhere" code isn't replaced with the Module i wanted to load within Joomla.